# Adding items to anonymous lists via code

Tags: sharepoint, list, anonymous

We have a custom list inside a moss publishing site that an asp.net form is submitting information to.

We seem unable to submit the form when accessing the site anonymously, though we have turned off viewformspageslockdown, have enabled anonymous access on the site and allowed add anon on the list itself.

We can navigate to the list and add a new item from the moss gui but from our asp.net page, when we submit, it redirects to the login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous Means Read-Only, If you want to enable the user to add items while in Anonymous you need to use the [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543467.aspx) in the ASP.NET Page code.

Comment: but anonymous users can add via the moss ui? so is it different from the code

Comment: Be careful using  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: No I have never see an Option in MOSS UI for an Anonymous User  that will help him/her to add an Item.

Comment: @kusek - I was meaning that I can add an item to the list using the new button on the list OOTB interface

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the **security** on the **Custom List** to ensure that the anonymous users can modify the list items.  You should be able to check the effective security in site administration.